# how to config my customized serializer model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

i wanna set this serializer for accept just binary numbers, but its accepting just 1 or 0.
its not accepting 10010101 or others like that.
how can i make a function for contains just 1 and 0 numbers.

```
from .models import Binary
from rest_framework import serializers

class BinarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_binNum(self, value):
        if value is not 1 or 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('binary number must have just 0 or 1.')




    class Meta:
        model = Binary 
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Please include the code of `Binary` model.

Comment: class Binary(models.Model):
    binNum = models.PositiveIntegerField()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the binary number as a `models.PositiveInteger`, you can store it as a `models.CharField` and whenever you want to validate the input you can do this:

```
def validate_binNum(self, value):
  try:
    number = int(value, 2)
  except ValueError:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('binary number must have just 0 or 1.')
```

Whenever you want to use the value, you can simply do `number = int(binNum, 2)`